# Xcode "Open with External Editor"

Tags: xcode, editor

How can I determine which editor should be called in Xcode 14.2 when I select "Open with External Editor" for a file with the right mouse button?
For me, a Markdown editor is always started, also for the Swift files.
In old tips it says you have to set the appropriate editor via the Finder. But when I open a Swift file with a double click in the Finder, it works ...

Answer (score 1):

Xcode currently doesn't have a way to let you know what editor when you choose Open with External Editor.

The editor Xcode uses to open the file depends on the file type. For each file type you must set the default editor to use from the Finder.

1. Select a file in the Finder.
2. Press Cmd-I to open the file's Info panel.
3. Choose a text editor from the Open with menu.
4. Click the Change All button to set the default editor for all files of that type.

[image]

After setting the default editor, choosing Open with External Editor in Xcode will open the file in the editor you specified.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But as I've already mentioned in my original posting, the default editor is set correctly from Finder. And opening a file with a double click works without an error ...

Comment: If my answer doesn't work, there's a bug in Xcode because setting the editor for a file type from the Finder is how you tell Xcode what external editor to use. File a bug report with Apple. You can do it from Xcode by choosing Help > Report an Issue.